# joomla falang add translation for ignite gallery

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

As i am new to `joomla` i don't get any idea how to make translations work as they are ment to work...... Currently i am trying to add translation to `ignite gallery component` using this `xml file` to specify what to translate

"`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<falang type="contentelement">
<name>Ignite Gallery v1.0 Main</name>
<author>Matthew Thomson</author>
<version>1.0</version>
<description>Ignite Gallery v1.0 Main</description>
    <reference>
        <table name="igallery">
            <field type="referenceid" name="id" translate="0">ID</field>
            <field type="titletext" name="name" translate="1">Name</field>
            <field type="htmltext" name="menu_description" translate="1">Menu Description</field>
            <field type="htmltext" name="gallery_description" translate="1">Gallery Description</field>
            <field type="text" name="alias" translate="0">Alias</field>
        </table>
    </reference>
</falang>`"

The problem now is that it translates from English to Russian but when i try to translate from Russian to English `falang` overwrites the main language with russian.

It would be nice if you could explain me why......

**EDIT:**

I am not trying to translate gallery itselve i am trying to translate images name, description and menu description using that xml file

Comment: If you are translating from Russian to English, won't be Russian the default language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have installed joomla's Russian language package on your website:

- go to your website root folder
- locate languages folder
- go to en-GB folder
- find en-GB.com_ignitegallery.ini (or whatever your component name is)
- copy it inside ru-RU folder in the languages folder
- change it's name to ru-RU.com_ignitegallery.ini
- open it
- translate it
- done!

Now all you need is to change your website's language to Russian.